# How to make automatic chart size adjustment in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a problem with the size of the displayed image during dataframe visualization. Is it possible to adjust the x-axis to fit all subtitles and make the graph readable?
[image: screen]

Comment: Create a big enough `Axes` using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(....,....))` and pass it when plotting... `...kind='bar', ax=ax)`.

Comment: another option is to pass `figsize=(20,6)` to the plot command.